# Java: Having a 'title window' before a Login Screen

Tags: java, eclipse, splash-screen

I'm currently working on a Java project application for University and it already has a login screen of which loads when the program is ran, and then goes on to the relevant other interfaces.

Anyway, I was wondering how I could have a window to appear for maybe 3 seconds, before the login screen loads, which would simply show the logo of the software (just like you see on Office programs when you first open them and the small window before the main document comes up). Would it require the use of threads to make the window close automatically?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: search for _splash screen java_, I guess you'll find many tutorials. The first hit on google is [How to Create a Splash Screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) from the Oracle Java tutorials.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html

Comment: Why should the OP Google anything?  He has people to do that for him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was always wondering what pattern is that (i guess now its name is `splash screen java`) when running a java desktop application and getting that window in the middle of the screen witch seems to be doing somthing (but what exactly...) and witch in some apps annoyingly stays on top and hides other stuff.

To answer your question you could just draw a title window centered and with disabled pannel for the close/maximize/minize buttons and go sleep for 3 seconds [Thread.sleep(3000L)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) then hide the window and continue to the login screen

Or you could while showing the title window do something useful instead of just waiting and start a new Thread to initializing other gui-elements and other stuff that your application might need and wait for that thread to terminate using [Thread.join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29). When the thread terminates you can hide the window and proceed to the login screen. Thea waiting time would be in this case the time needed for init routine

Also you could consider just putting the logo an title somewhere in a corner on the login screen.

As a user of that software i would not apreciate to wait 3 seconds just watching a logo especialy when the application does nothing.

Hope this helps